# Script to set the default image description text?

Tags: support, editing, script-request, images

Stack Exchange sets `enter image description here` as the default description —  this is mainly useful for new users who may not know that the title can be modified.

I'm looking for a script to automatically set a specified description for every image, for instance "screenshot" would be a suitable for the majority of images I upload as I mainly use the technology SE sites.

Comment: Please provide "hover text" by following this syntax: https://stackapps.com/questions/6144/alt-text-to-hover-text#comment13213_6144

Comment: Never mind that, add resizing syntax per the answers at [this MetaSE Q](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314028/the-stack-imgur-service-is-no-longer-resizing-images-correctly).  I will make this script myself, eventually, if no one beats me (to it).  Note that [official changes are underfoot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317576/148310).